# Preload tableView cells and prevent reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, preload

I already found entries with that topic on this page and also a website that provides a tutorial for that problem. But nothing worked very well.

The tutorial sad I should double the height of my tableView so cells loaded earlier, but with a higher tableView I never reached the last cells.

My problem is, I use a tableView to display my apps mainpage. This mainPage shows every time a topic and if its necessary for that topic it shows for example a cell with a map, one with pictures and sometimes not. Problem now, if I trying to scroll to my view its always lagging because it loads a map or this pictures. And scrolling back again because the loaded cells already deleted. I used a tableView because of the possibility to switch celltypes(mapCell, pictureCell, textCell) on and off.

I understand this feature, because of memory issues but in my case its not that much and it would be better if all my cells be preloaded and stay in memory until I change the topic.

Is there a swifty way to told my tableView to have this behavior?

Thanks a lot and nice greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a cell array.

Follow these steps whenever change in your topic.

1. Clear you array
2. Create and configure all cells add to your array.
3. Return these cells to datasource methods using row index. Don't use tableview dequeue method here.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm so embarrassed! How simple was that! I thank you so much!

Comment: This works but it's not memory-efficient. Better to pre-load the model data and still use the cell dequeue method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Set up your table view controller to install placeholder images in your cells, trigger an async download that you cache to disk, and then update the cell with it's downloaded content if it's still visible when the download is finished.

There are various third party frameworks that do all this housekeeping for you.

Comment: yes, another method, but I think its okay! I have a memoryusage between 30-60 mb or is that to much?

Comment: On a newer device 30-60 mb should not be a problem. How many table view entries are we talking, and how big are the images?

Comment: iOS 9 runs on the 4s and above. That's your current lowest spec device. iOS 10 will drop the 4s and only run on the 5 and above.

Comment: It is a maximum of 6 cells. Some of the cells always there some are variable.

Comment: The 3 Cells that always there have 1. one image 550x1200 (not optimized jet) 2. one image 250x250(not optimized jet too) both loaded from a Database. The 3 variable cells are one with MapView, one with some text and one with a tableView that have 3 cells each with a image 320x180 also loaded from a Database. And there are some other little icons with just around 2-20kb

Comment: I testing on a iPhone 4s and a ipad mini 1th gen, both works fine. Only xcode shows on Energy Impact just High-Very High, but this was also before I changed to hold all cells. If I'm honest I wondering about that my app is not doing anything but showing content.